# How to add image in OBIEE?

Tags: obiee

I am coding some basic html code just to display an image banner to our OBIEE dashboard but failed to do so. I am a newbie in terms of programming so feel free to correct me in anyway. So, here's the detail.

I am currently working in the static text layout where the old banner was coded, I remove them and replace with a basic code that only import an image see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90JSM.png).

*Oracle Business Intelligence 12.2.1.4.0

I have tried coding it thru HTML,CSS, & Javascript those only the few I basically know. I did my research and follow some tutorials but no glimpse of hope to it, it does work when I relay the output in a browser while coding it in Visual Studio.

What I want is just to display it successfully and not to show a image icon. Hope someone can help me out. Thank You :)

Comment: I unfortunately can't view the Imgur domain from where I am. Is that your code? A demonstration of what it looks like? If it's important, you will likely want to embed it with a proper description. And if it's code, please quote it, especially since some people are using screen readers.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Sorry about that. Yes, a basic "img src" code was on display sample. It didn't work and only show a image icon.

Comment: Can you view the image going directly to that URL?

Comment: If you mean the sample image then Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am struggling to comprehend where Visual Studio comes into this but assuming you want to just have an image on a dashboard then there are lots of options

It looks like you are trying to insert a remote image which is going to cause all sorts of security issues that are likely to mean it will get blocked.

The simplest is to just add a "link or Image" object and use a local image.  If you click on the select image button there is an option to upload image and select it for display.

If you want to use html then you just need to add a text object and add the img html
`<img src="https://someurl.com/img.jpg" />`
but you are going to need to change lot of security policies to allow the content to be displayed.

There are other options to host the file locally such as a shared folder (https://gianniceresa.com/2017/02/obiee-12c-custom-style-using-shared-folder/) but the upload is far simpler.

If you insist of using a remote image you will need to understand security policies (CSP, XSS etc.) which aren't OBIEE specific but standard web server

Comment: That's very helpful information Sir, Thanks. About the Visual Studio I tried to test out the code if it works, the reason why because it didn't work at OBIEE so I presumed there's something wrong with the code. 

"The simplest is to just add a "link or Image" object and use a local image. If you click on the select image button there is an option to upload image and select it for display."

About this sentence I looked at it again in the OBIEE, I don't seem to see any button or function that could add a link or image, do I need to code it? Hope you'll excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Take a look at https://datacadamia.com/dat/obiee/obips/image
I don't access to OBIEE right now but since 12c there are options to upload images via the image selection screen.   I will try and grab a screenshot at some point.   If you are using 11g then the option isn't there but that has been out of support for some time anyway

Comment: I think I figured out where was that upload function you're talking about base on this link https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4146365/obiee-12c-upload-image-location. But the problem when I test it out uploading an image it only cap at 50k https://snipboard.io/IXKwDp.jpg but referred to the link I provided it doesn't look like it. I have read the article you provided and to what I understand it only refers to previous version of OBIEE like you've said and this particular part https://snipboard.io/kKjGM9.jpg specially the highlight one there's no function like that...

Comment: ...in the static view https://snipboard.io/PGuofd.jpg. Also about the directory path where you upload your wanted image/s, I somehow figured out the path but it seems to be cut off "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\domains\bi\servers\obis1\tmp" in Oracle folder there should be few following folder like \...\res\ to where I put the image and also some generated file referring to the first link I've sent. I didn't try to experiment creating it, scared might affect some file or to the OBIEE itself since I am a newly employed BI specialist :(. Also I appreciate the help man :)

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a 50KB limit but bhis becomes architectural rather than OBIEE specific... 
If you attempt to manually upload to the tmp folder you will loose your images on a restart.   
If you follow Oracle reference architecture you will have OHS as the HTTP server in front of BI and that would allow you to host whatever images you want.   If you don't want to / can't install OHS then go for the shared folder (https://gianniceresa.com/2017/02/obiee-12c-custom-style-using-shared-folder/ ignoring the bits about custom styles)

Comment: Also for HTML you do not need a full html declaration only a snippet.   If you need an image just add `<img src='ddd.jpg' />` If you create the shared folder as above and reference is analyticsres/res you can add `<img src='/analyticsres/res/myimage.jpg' />`

Comment: Always funny to see threads filled with old stuff from Gianni and myself. Good old times.